# Local json object not working in Typahead Bloodhound

Tags: json, wordpress, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I am using Typeahead Bootstrap in a form field (with a WP framework).

I have a .json file stored in my root, which I can grab using prefetch:

```
prefetch: {
  url: '
    ../json/test.json',
    ttl: 1
}
```

menu works just fine. Now, let's say I dont want to use prefetch, but load the datum in a local json array.

I have the same json file that looks like:

```
[{"title":"Title 1","content":"Loopty loos"},{"title":"Title 2","content":"Diddly Bones"}]
```

If I load that directly into the new Bloodhound class:

```
local:  [{"title":"Title 1","content":"Loopty loos"},{"title":"Title 2","content":"Diddly Bones"}]
```

again, works like a charm. However, if I try to load the same data in as a variable, rather than explicitly written:

jsonObject = [{"title":"Title 1","content":"Loopty loos"},{"title":"Title 2","content":"Diddly Bones"}]

```
 var content = new Bloodhound({
   datumTokenizer: function (d) { 
     return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.content);
   },
   local: jsonObject
   ...
```

It doesn't work. This seems like it's something simple and I am just completely missing it.

Full clarification, I am querying the wp database, and with that result set creating the json file and writing it to the test directory, then passing it to a .js file using wp_localize_script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After declaring Bloodhound object, try to initialize the object.

```
var content = new Bloodhound({
   datumTokenizer: function (d) { 
     return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.content);
   },
   local: jsonObject
   ...
})
```

content.initialize();